# Entity Framework One-Many TPH Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using a data structure similar to this where type of animal is determined from a discriminator column in the table:

```
public class Farm {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Pig> Pigs { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cow> Cows { get; set; }
}

public class Animal {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FarmId? { get; set; }

    public virtual Farm Farm { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Pig : Animal {}
public class Cow : Animal {}
```

Mapping:

```
this.Map<Pig>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue((int) AnimalType.Pig));
this.Map<Cow>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue((int) AnimalType.Cow));
```

But I can't seem to map the relationship between the Pigs, Cows and Farm. I've tried this from `FarmMap` which gives a duplicate column mapping error:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Pigs)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Farm)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("FarmId"));
this.HasMany(t => t.Cows)
    .WithOptional(t => t.Farm)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("FarmId"));
```

Mapping from each of the animals doesn't work either, it generates extra columns (eg. `Farm_Id` and `Farm_Id1` - in addition to `FarmId` - one for each animal type).

```
this.HasOptional(t => t.Farm)
    .WithMany(t => t.Pigs)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.FarmId)
```

Moving the navigation property from the `Animal` model to the inheriting models causes a single additional column to be generated - `FarmId1` (so a little closer to what I want than the above 2!)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for you situation, that's what i've been looking for..

Answer (score 0):

I'm no EF expert but from the Model-first approach I know that this would be mapped as a collection of Animal, you can then select `Farm.Animals.OfType<Pig>()`

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the whole collection of Animals is loaded from the SQL Server then filtered into those which are pigs?

Comment: (Which was what I was trying to avoid with this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663337/entity-framework-filtered-navigation-properties)